# Federal Information Processing Standard Publication (FIPS) in .NET and Azure

Tags: azure, security

I am trying to adhere to the Federal Information Processing Standard Publication (FIPS) security standards.
My web application is built with C# .NET, published to Azure using SQL Server for storing user login credentials.
Once a user logs in, I use
       _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
to generate a GUID.  This GUID is then used to select the proper CosmoDB database, also on Azure.  The CosmoDB is what has all the sensitive information - SQL Server is used just for logging in and selecting the proper CosmoDB.

What do I need to do to ensure FIPS standards are met?  Does the Identity library provide some tools I need?  Right now everything is pretty standard, I used the basic templates for SQL Server logins and for uploading to Azure.  Is this secure enough for FIPS?

Comment: Might want to update your tags. I'm having a hard time connecting this to a data binding JavaScript library.

Comment: It's nuanced. You can see ASP.NET Identity is FIPS aware. (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/e38759b8a2de1b7a4a1c19462e40214b43c1cf3b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service.Core/CryptographyHelpers.cs#L56) The framework will always use SHA256 there, but the framework will only use the FIPS validated implementation of SHA256 if the "FIPS bit" is on in Windows. You could enable the bit on a VM, but not in an app service.